# Linear equation from log equation

Tags: logarithms

Further mathematics is driving crazy at the moment as I prepare for a PHD in chem eng.

I've been working hard at the books but this one has caught me out. I basically need to derive a linear equation.

$ \ \log_2(x + 1) -1 \ = \ 2 \ \ \log_2 y \ $

I know that I need to raise two to the power of both sides of the second equation

$2^{\log_2 z}=z$ is the law I'm going to utilize

Further, the laws of exponentials should lead me to the linear equation I'm after.

I'm at $(x+1)^2 -1 = 2^2 y$ but can't tell if I'm completely lost.

Comment: Log base 2? Please format your equations using subscripts etc... $\log_2$ is \$\log_2\$.

Comment: By $2 \log^2 z= z$ do you mean $2 (\log_2 z)^2=z$ ? In this case, it is not a law... It is true for $z=2$ and $z \approx 0.67$, that's all.

Comment: No I meant $2^{\log_2 z}=z$.

Comment: Sorry all I have rectified my post to reflect what I was trying to state

Comment: For the left hand side, $$2^{\log_2(x+1)-1} = \frac{x+1}2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\log_2(x+1)-\log_2 2$$ because you can write 1 as $\log_2 2$

now principle of logarithms: $\log_ab-\log_ac=\log_a(b/c)$
$$\implies\log_2(\frac{x+1}{2})$$
and this equation is equal to you LHS
$$\log_2(\frac{x+1}{2})=2\log_2y$$
Now RHS you can write as $\log_2y^2$ because $a\log b=\log b^a$

now since bases of LHS and RHS are equal. we can equate to$$\frac{x+1}{2}=y^2$$

Comment: You have a typo. It is $\frac{x+\color{red}1}{2}=y^2$

Comment: @callculus where?

Comment: The red one-I think.

Comment: aha! thanks @callculus

Comment: You´re welcome. Now I can upvote the answer. But the domains are $x>-1$ and $y>0$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, but the answer should be

```
y = root((x+1)/2)
```

Because if you try to put a negative value for `y` in the question, it won't work. With the answer of

```
y^2 = (x+1)/2
```

Negative y values do work, and that is not the same.

[image]